# Unable to open sqlite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using two databases: `SYSTEM_DB1` and `USER_DB1`. `SYSTEM_DB1` is being copied from assets to the phone memory using [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). `USER_DB1` is created simply by extending `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Following are some key points abt the code:

- I have tried to use `ATTACH` command in sqlite to use both databases
  simultaneously in my activity.
- There is an old database `Db_bunduled` that i will be accessing in order to extract old data and then delete it.

Following is the code of my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();

SystemDBAssetHelper sys_db=new SystemDBAssetHelper(this);
UserDBHelper user_db = new UserDBHelper(this);

boolean b=sys_db.checkDataBase(this, USER_DATABASE_NAME_1);
Log.d(TAG, "USER_DB1 exists:"+b);

b=sys_db.checkDataBase(this, SYSTEM_DATABASE_NAME_1);
Log.d(TAG, "SYSTEM_DB1 exists:"+b);


user_db.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(
        String.format("ATTACH DATABASE %s AS %s;",
                SYSTEM_DATABASE_NAME_1, SYSTEM_DATABASE_NAME_1));
Log.d(TAG, "after attaching sysdb");
user_db.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(
        String.format("ATTACH DATABASE %s AS %s;",
                USER_DATABASE_NAME_1, USER_DATABASE_NAME_1));
Log.d(TAG, "after attaching userdb");
Cursor cursor = user_db
        .getReadableDatabase()
        .rawQuery(
                String.format(
                        "SELECT * FROM %s.%s INNER JOIN %s.%s ON %s.%s = %s.%s;",
                        USER_DATABASE_NAME_1, TABLE_LEARNT_WORDS,
                        SYSTEM_DATABASE_NAME_1, TABLE_SYS_DICTIONARY,
                        TABLE_LEARNT_WORDS, ENTRY_ID,
                        TABLE_SYS_DICTIONARY, ENTRY_ID), null);

//...

    user_db.close();
}
```

Following is the code for SystemDBAssetHelper:

```
public class SystemDBAssetHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper implements Constants {
    String DB_PATH; 
    public SystemDBAssetHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, SYSTEM_DATABASE_NAME_1, null, 1);
        DB_PATH= context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir +
                "/databases/";



        if (checkDataBase(context, DATABASE_NAME_OLD)) {
            OldDbHelper oldDB = new OldDbHelper(context);
            String[] currArgs = { String.valueOf(OldDbHelper.STATUS_LEARNT) };
            Cursor cursor = oldDB.getReadableDatabase().query(
                    TABLE_SYS_DICTIONARY, null, OldDbHelper.WORD_STATUS + "=?",
                    currArgs, null, null, null);

        //...

            cursor.close();
            oldDB.close();

            Iterator<String> it = al.iterator();

            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String[] Args = { String.valueOf(it.next()) };

                Cursor cursor1 = this.getReadableDatabase().query(
                        TABLE_SYS_DICTIONARY, null, WORD + "=?", Args, null,
                        null, null);

                UserDBHelper user_db = new UserDBHelper(context);

                //...

                user_db.close();

            }

        }

    }

    public boolean checkDataBase(Context context, String DB_NAME) {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;


        try {
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH+DB_NAME, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            // e.printStackTrace();
            return false;

        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;




    }
}
```

Following is the code for UserDBHelper:

```
public class UserDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements Constants {

    public UserDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, USER_DATABASE_NAME_1, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        Log.d(TAG, "starting oncreate in userdbhelper");
        String stmt_learntWords = String.format(
                "CREATE TABLE %s (%s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, %s TEXT NOT NULL);",
                TABLE_LEARNT_WORDS, _ID, ENTRY_ID);
        db.execSQL(stmt_learntWords);

//...

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        //no code
    }

}
```

Following are the logs:

```
06-23 16:17:45.830: I/Database(2910): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27205 of [42537b6056]
06-23 16:17:45.830: E/Database(2910): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.vishal.myapp/databases/Db_bunduled", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
06-23 16:17:45.830: I/Database(2910): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27205 of [42537b6056]
06-23 16:17:45.830: E/Database(2910): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.vishal.myapp/databases/USER_DB1", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
06-23 16:17:45.830: D/vishal(2910): USER_DB1 exists:false
06-23 16:17:45.840: I/Database(2910): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27205 of [42537b6056]
06-23 16:17:45.840: E/Database(2910): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.vishal.myapp/databases/SYSTEM_DB1", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
06-23 16:17:45.840: D/vishal(2910): SYSTEM_DB1 exists:false
06-23 16:17:45.869: D/vishal(2910): starting oncreate in userdbhelper
06-23 16:17:45.879: D/vishal(2910): ending oncreate in userdbhelper
06-23 16:17:45.889: I/Database(2910): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27205 of [42537b6056]
06-23 16:17:45.889: I/Database(2910): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = statement aborts at 5: [ATTACH DATABASE SYSTEM_DB1 AS SYSTEM_DB1;] unable to open database: SYSTEM_DB1
06-23 16:17:45.889: E/Database(2910): Failure 14 (unable to open database: SYSTEM_DB1) on 0x225858 when executing 'ATTACH DATABASE SYSTEM_DB1 AS SYSTEM_DB1;'
06-23 16:17:45.889: D/AndroidRuntime(2910): Shutting down VM
06-23 16:17:45.889: W/dalvikvm(2910): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
06-23 16:17:45.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2910): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-23 16:17:45.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2910): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.vishal.myapp/com.vishal.myapp.ActivityLearntWords}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database: SYSTEM_DB1: ATTACH DATABASE SYSTEM_DB1 AS SYSTEM_DB1;

//...

06-23 16:17:45.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2910): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unable to open database: SYSTEM_DB1: ATTACH DATABASE SYSTEM_DB1 AS SYSTEM_DB1;
06-23 16:17:45.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2910):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_execSQL(Native Method)
06-23 16:17:45.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2910):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1763)
06-23 16:17:45.899: E/AndroidRuntime(2910):     at com.vishal.myapp.ActivityLearntWords.onResume(ActivityLearntWords.java:47)

//...
```

Following are the permission details in the .../databases/ directory of the app:

```
-rw-rw----    1 app_55   app_55        8192 Jun 23 16:17 USER_DB1
-rw-rw----    1 app_55   app_55        1024 Jun 23 16:17 webview.db
-rw-r--r--    1 app_55   app_55       32768 Jun 23 16:17 webview.db-shm
-rw-r--r--    1 app_55   app_55       17848 Jun 23 16:17 webview.db-wal
-rw-rw----    1 app_55   app_55        1024 Jun 23 16:17 webviewCache.db
-rw-r--r--    1 app_55   app_55       32768 Jun 23 16:17 webviewCache.db-shm
-rw-r--r--    1 app_55   app_55       20992 Jun 23 16:17 webviewCache.db-wal
```

Comment: you dont need to provide the path of the database files they by default to the directory you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to access the database which was not yet created in the activity.

```
user_db.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(
        String.format("ATTACH DATABASE %s AS %s;",
                SYSTEM_DATABASE_NAME_1, SYSTEM_DATABASE_NAME_1));
```

The database file is not created by merely calling the constructor. I had to call `sys_db.getWritableDatabase()` first before any other database related operation.

Also, from the [official documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html), I got to know that the original table is referred as 'main'.

To avoid any confusion, here's my final code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    SystemDBAssetHelper sys_db = new SystemDBAssetHelper(this);
            sys_db.getWritableDatabase();
            sys_db.close();


    String FIRST_DB_PATH = this.getDatabasePath(SYSTEM_DATABASE_NAME_1)
            .toString();

    UserDBHelper user_db = new UserDBHelper(this);
    user_db.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(
            String.format("ATTACH DATABASE '%s' AS %s;", FIRST_DB_PATH,
                    SYSTEM_DATABASE_NAME_1));

    Cursor cursor = user_db
            .getReadableDatabase()
            .rawQuery(
                    String.format(
                            "SELECT * FROM %s.%s INNER JOIN %s.%s ON %s.%s = %s.%s;",
                            "main", TABLE_USER,
                            SYSTEM_DATABASE_NAME_1, TABLE_SYS,
                            TABLE_USER, ENTRY_ID,
                            TABLE_SYS, ENTRY_ID), null);

    //...

    cursor.close();
    user_db.close();
}
```